# sort parent element based on contents of child element - javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a monthly calendar which displays days with events happening in this day. This is how generated HTML looks like:

```
<table class="event-cal">
  <tbody>
     <tr class="eventcont event-93">
        <td class="eventtime">19:00</td>
        <td><a class="calendar-title" href="#>Event title</a><br></td></tr>
     <tr class="eventcont event-237">
        <td class="eventtime">13:00</td>
        <td><a class="calendar-title" href="#">Event 2 title</a><br></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is to order **tr.eventcont** elements based on contents of **.eventtime** child element. Ordering has to be done within **.event-cal** element which contains these particular **.eventcont** elements because I will have several .event-cal elements in the page.

Here is the code I have so far but what it does it takes all tr.eventcont elements from page and pastes them all into each .event-cal table.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var list = $(".event-cal").find(".eventcont");
        list.sort(sortDesc);
        $(".event-cal").html("");
        $(".event-cal").append(list);
    });
    function sortDesc(a, b){
        var test1 = jQuery(a);
        var test2 = jQuery(b);
        return test1.find(".eventtime").text() > test2.find(".eventtime").text();
}
```

Comment: You're appending to $(".event-cal"), which is every table that has the class 'event-cal'. If you want it to only append it to the table you're finding them in, you need to specify this function for each table appart, like in the answers.

Comment: It should be noted that the sort function seems flawed, for instance `"10:00" < "2:00"` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your function for each table using [`jquery.fn.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('.event-cal').each(function() {
   var table = $(this),
      list = table.find('.eventcont').sort(sortDesc);

   table.empty().append(list);      
});
```

Comment: @Yury, can you please explain this function? I'm testing it, but I get *sortDesc is not defined*

Comment: @Vixed sortDesc is the function that Daria created on the question.

Comment: ups, sorry! I was working on my answer that's why I haven't seen it, ahahah I didn't used ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/nr723gzh/)**

```
$(".event-cal").each(function(){
  var events=$('tr',this);
  events.sort(function (a, b) {
      a = parseInt($('.eventtime',a).text().replace(':',''));
      b = parseInt($('.eventtime',b).text().replace(':',''));
      if(a > b) {
          return 1;
      } else if(a < b) {
          return -1;
      } else {
          return 0;
      }
  });
  $(this).html(events);
});
```